# Removing PivotTable label that appears when 2 items in "Value" area

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a PivotTable.

However I am getting an extra row appearing above my titles with the word "Values" in one of the cells. This naturally comes from the "COLUMNS" area, as a field is automatically appearing in it.

This only appears when I have 2 or more fields in the "VALUES" area. With 1 it is not present.

I don't want it and cant see a way of getting rid of it. Deleting it also removes the two fields in the "VALUES" area.

[image: PivotTable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click the pivot table and select "Pivot Table Options...", then in "Display" tab of the new window there is checker for "Show the Values row". Uncheck it and is should disappear.